# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: proguard

Релизную сборку для данного приложения cобирал с *ProGuard* много раз, для *targetSdk 25*. Предпоследнюю выпустил для *targetSdk 26*. *ProGuard* не ругался. Затем последнюю понизил опять до *targetSdk 25*. Код работает нормально, но приходится подавлять предупреждение:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbga: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgb: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED in 10s
Information:1 error
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Подавляю предупреждение любой из двух команд в *proguard rules-pro*: `-dontwarn **`  или `-ignorewarning`, но хотелось бы найти ошибку.

В *Gradle Console* вижу:

```
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
```

Comment: Я так понимаю ProGuard удаляет неиспользуемые файлы подключенной библиотеки, а Gradle ругается.

Comment: Тогда почему не помогает -keep class android.content.pm.PackageManager.**